# android camera2 api access to my both rear camera

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I have `phone` with `2` rear cameras. I tired to access both of using `android.hardware.camera2 CameraManager`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String[] camerasIds = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

But camerasIds array contains only 2 ids. What may cause this problem?